# Three basic questions about linear operator in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Just come across three questions in reading a paper.

Suppose we are dealing with a Hilbert space of $L_{2}[0,1]$ and all the functions mentioned below are in $L_{2}[0,1]$.

Define the operator $A$ by
\begin{equation}
(Av)(w):=\int^{1}_{0}v(x)f_{XW}(x,w)dx.
\end{equation}
Let $\left\{ \psi_{j}: j=1,2,... \right\}$ be a complete, orthonormal basis for $L_{2}[0,1]$, so that 
\begin{equation}
f_{XW}(x,w)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_{jk}\psi_{j}(x)\psi_{k}(w).
\end{equation}
The paper says: Let $A_{n}$ be the operator on $L_{2}[0,1]$ whose kernel is 
\begin{equation}
a_{n}(x,w)=\sum_{j=1}^{J_{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{J_{n}}c_{jk}\psi_{j}(x)\psi_{k}(w).
\end{equation}
My first question is: Does this mean that $A_{n}$ is an operator such that 
\begin{equation}
(A_{n}v)(w):=\int^{1}_{0}v(x)a_{n}(x,w)dx?
\end{equation}

It also says
\begin{equation}
(A_{n}^{-1}\psi_{k})(x)=\sum^{J_{n}}_{j=1}c^{jk}\psi_{j}(x),
\end{equation}
where $c^{jk}$ is the $(j,k)$ element of the inverse of the $J_{n}\times J_{n}$ matrix $[c_{jk}]$.

My second question is that: Is this because $A_{n}^{-1}$ has kernel as 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^{J_{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{J_{n}}c^{jk}\psi_{j}(x)\psi_{k}(w)?
\end{equation}

My third question: is this true that
\begin{equation}
\sup_{\parallel h \parallel \neq 0} \frac{\parallel h \parallel}{\parallel(A^{\ast}A)^{1/2}h\parallel}
=\sup_{\parallel h \parallel \neq 0} \frac{\parallel h \parallel}{\parallel Ah\parallel}?
\end{equation}

Comment: With regards to your third question,
$$
 \|(A^\ast A)^{1/2}h \| = \langle (A^\ast A)^{1/2}h, (A^\ast A)^{1/2} \rangle^{1/2} = \langle h, A^\ast A h \rangle^{1/2} = ?
$$

Comment: I see, Braminir. Thank you.